# how to solve quadratic programming in SVM

Tags: svm

In SVM we have 
$$\max_{\alpha}1^T{\alpha}-\frac{1}{2}{\alpha^T}Q{\alpha}$$
$$s.t.\quad{\alpha^T}y=0,\quad{\alpha} \ge0 $$
If we have 3 data points and 2 dimensional example  in SVM

the Q matrix become(symmetric matrix in quadratic form):
$$(Q)_{ij}=y_iy_jx_i^Tx_j$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
y_0y_0x_0^Tx_0 & y_0y_1x_0^Tx_1 & y_0y_2x_0^Tx_2 \\
y_1y_0x_1^Tx_0 & y_1y_1x_1^Tx_1 & y_1y_2x_1^Tx_2 \\
y_2y_0x_2^Tx_0 & y_2y_1x_2^Tx_1 & y_2y_2x_2^Tx_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and alpha matrix(the dimension depends on how many points in this example 3):
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
{\alpha_1}\\
{\alpha_2}\\
{\alpha_3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
after multiply 
$$\frac{1}{2}{\alpha^T}Q{\alpha}$$
as a result something like:
$$
{\alpha_1}^2-6{\alpha_1}+9+{\alpha_2}^2+2{\alpha_2}+1
$$
and subject to
$$
{\alpha_1}y_1+{\alpha_2}y_2+{\alpha_3}y_3=0$$
$$
{\alpha_i\ge0}
$$
How do I solve with Quadratic Programming?
In svm it is so different form classic quadratic programming problem
I don't know how to solve with the constraint because it has y value